# Detect change made in devtools

Tags: javascript, jquery, mutation-observers

I am trying to detect if attribute was changed in devtools or in js script.

I created a `MutationObserver` object, but I don't know how to detect the difference if this is a change triggered in devtools or in js script.

Vraiable `$modalImg` is an jQuery variable with image tag.
`attributeValue` is a new value after change. In this case this is attribute `src` value.

I want to detect `src` attribute change to prevent users from changing it, but I would like to allow js script to change `src` attribute.

Is that even possible, or maybe I should do it completely differently?

```js
var srpImageObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
            if (mutation.attributeName === "src") {
                var $element = $(mutation.target),
                    attributeValue = $element.prop(mutation.attributeName);

                console.log(mutation)
        });
   });

srpImageObserver.observe($modalImg[0], {
    attributes: true
});
```

Comment: Set some global (or in-app) boolean flag before changing it in your script, and in your observer restore it if the flag isn't set.

Comment: Let's say you find a way to detect the change came from the DevTools (which I don't think there is). What prevents the user from using said DevTools to remove the `MutationObserver`, thus defeating the whole idea?

Comment: I don't think this is possible on a theoretical level (if the user understands the script, there is nothing you can do), but security by obscurity, as described on other comments, can ward off the simplest of attempts.

Comment: You can add a timer e.g. setInterval to detect changes. Timer will keep checking the src attribute.

Comment: Thanks to all of you for quick response. I used flag as wOxxOm suggested and it works the way I wanted it to. But also what Zenoo said is true that if user disable the `MutationObserver` he will change the attribute anyway.

Comment: By the way, will `MutationObserver` observe dynamically created elements?